# expected value of filtered binomial

Tags: bernoulli-distribution

Assume a bernoulli random variable with success probability p. In 12 independent trials of the bernoulli I only look at the third, sixth, nineth and twelfth experiment. What is the expected value of the number of successes that I observe at these four occasions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the trials are independent, the expected value is still $p$.

Comment: you mean $4p$ I assume?

Comment: You wrote "What is the expected value of the number of successes that I observe at these four occasions?", then at each occasion the expected value is $p$. Of course, if you want to know the expected number of success in these four occasion, it is $4p$.

Comment: OK I see your point. +1